# Button to show/hide div has to be pressed twice

Tags: javascript, html, button

My Goal:  to have my div hidden on page load and show/hide the div with a button using only HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

I have set up a button in HTML and JavaScript to show/hide my div which works great when the div is visible on page load and not hidden using CSS.  When I hide the div using CSS display: none; the div is hidden on page load but the button has to be clicked twice before the div becomes visible.

HTML:

```
  <button class="btn btn-link" id="btnLink" onclick="hideLink()">Hide 
  Content</button> <br><br>
  <div id="myLink">
  <h1>Div content here</h1>
  </div>
```

CSS:

#myLink {display: none;}

JavaScript:

```
function hideLink() {
var x = document.getElementById('myLink');
var b = document.getElementById('btnLink');


if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
    b.childNodes[0].nodeValue="Hide Content";

} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    b.childNodes[0].nodeValue="Show Content";
}
}
```

Comment: If you `console.log(x.style.display)` on page load while it is hidden using CSS, what is the value?

Comment: i'm not sure how can I check the value?

Comment: the div at first time while you click btn, you didn't set any value in display, so you call x.style.display is neither block nor none, the problem should be here

Comment: the CSS block `#myLink {display: none;}` means that the element is hidden ... BUT, it has no inline style - therefore the first click will run the `else` block ... change your logic, check `if (display !== 'block')` instead

Comment: changing the logic works but wont hide the div now....

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30311244/1765658) !! There is a way of doing things like this, by using CSS only!

Answer (score 6):

> You should check for `!== 'block'` rather than `=== 'none'`

The value `x.style.display` is set to blank when we use `none` in the css as the css selector is what gets the `none` attribute than the element ( at lease that is what I understand ). So the check `=== none` actually compares it will blank and return false ( `x.style.display = ''`).

Now once we have set the value to `block` using JS the element's `style.display` property has a value which we can compare.

```js
function hideLink() {
  var x = document.getElementById('myLink');
  var b = document.getElementById('btnLink');


  if (x.style.display !== 'block') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
    b.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Hide Content";

  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    b.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Show Content";
  }
}
```

```css
#myLink {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-link" id="btnLink" onclick="hideLink()">
Show Content
</button>
<br><br>
<div id="myLink">
  <h1>Div content here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What is this magic,`!==`? How does this translate to one less click?

Comment: @AlexanderMcNulty I have updated the answer to describe what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the button is clicked, the element *itself* does not specifically have the style for display set.  After your first if/then, then it does.

See here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4peCJS1vhJskexqdLdKL?p=preview

```
var t = document.getElementById('output').innerText;
document.getElementById('output').innerText = JSON.stringify(x.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

corrected it with another if...

```
function hideLink() {
var x = document.getElementById('myLink');
var b = document.getElementById('btnLink');

if (x.style.display === ''){
    x.style.display = 'none';
}

if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
    b.childNodes[0].nodeValue="Hide Sitemap Section";

} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    b.childNodes[0].nodeValue="Show Sitemap Section";
}
}
```